# Search within a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array, sum

I have the following Array:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
    ( 
        [location] => Central>Europe>Italy
        [Total_S] => 4 
        [Total_R] => 0 
    ) 
)

Array 
( 
    [1] => Array 
    ( 
        [location] => Central>Europe>Spain
        [Total_S] => 4 
        [Total_R] => 0 
    ) 
)
```

There are over 100 in the array.

Is it possible to search within the array based on location, for example, I'd like to **sum** `Total_S` if `location` contains `Central>Europe'

In MySQL you can search using `LIKE`: `LIKE '%Central>Europe%'`

I don't know if PHP has the same functionality to do this within such an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking advantage of the new array_column() function in PHP 5.5:

```
$data = array(
    array( 
        'location' => 'Central>Europe>Italy',
        'Total_S' => 4,
        'Total_R' => 0,
    ),
    array( 
        'location' => 'Central>Europe>Spain',
        'Total_S' => 4,
        'Total_R' => 0,
    ),
    array( 
        'location' => 'Central>Africa>Egypt',
        'Total_S' => 4,
        'Total_R' => 0,
    ),
);
$search = 'Central>Europe>*';

$sum = array_sum(
    array_column(
        array_filter(
            $data,
            function($value) use ($search) {
                return fnmatch($search, $value['location']);
            }
        ),
        'Total_S'
    )
);
var_dump($sum);
```

**EDIT**

For earlier versions of PHP that don't have the array_column() function:

```
$column = 'Total_S';
$sum = array_sum(
    array_map(
        function($value) use ($column) {
            return $value[$column];
        },
        array_filter(
            $data,
            function($value) use ($search) {
                return fnmatch($search, $value['location']);
            }
        )
    )
);
```

(tested with 5.3.27)

**EDIT #2**

**Modified**: `return = array_sum(` **to** `return array_sum(`

```
$searchSubset = array_filter(
    $data,
    function($value) use ($search) {
        return fnmatch($search, $value['location']);
    }
);
function summer($data, $column) {
    return array_sum(
        array_map(
            function($value) use ($column) {
                return $value[$column];
            },
            $data
        )
    );
}
$sumS = summer($searchSubset, 'Total_S');
$sumR = summer($searchSubset, 'Total_R');
```

Comment: That looks perfect but I'm running PHP v 5.3.20 :-( - Any suggestions (other than upgrading)?

Comment: Perfect - as anside - is it possible to bring back both the `Total_S` AND the `Total_R`?

Comment: Thanks Mark - playing around with Edit #2 but it doesn't seem to be working.  No error messages, just a blank page - PHP problem?

Comment: Hi Mark - yes - it certainly is! :-)  One final question - if you don't mind me being cheeky - how do I re-use this multiple times on the same php page?  I've tried and it's not working - blank page when loading.

Comment: i.e I'd like to do lots of searches! :-)

Comment: You could easily create a function from the $searchSubset code: `function filter($data, $searchColumn, $searchTerm) { return array_filter(
    $data,
    function($value) use ($searchColumn, $searchTerm) {
        return fnmatch($searchTerm, $value[$searchColumn]);
    }
); }` and the `summer()` function is already reusable

Comment: If you're getting a blank page, enable error logging and check the php and webserver error logs; that should pinpoint any problem